# How do I remove querystring information after the name of JS file in wordpress and make it as cachable?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I use the below code in `footer.php`

```
<div id="apptivols"></div>
<script>
    $('#apptivols').fadeIn().delay(5000).queue(function() {
        $.getScript('https://d3u46tuvnoj4ah.cloudfront.net/app/v1.1/war/js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js');
        $('#apptivols').show();
    });
</script>
```

When I inspect the element in Firefoxs' "net" tab the `js` filename shows as

> https://d3u46tuvnoj4ah.cloudfront.net/app/v1.1/war/js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js_=320365284541

Why does it appear like this? How do I remove that querystring?..

It is not cached in browser. How can i cached this js in browser?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the Solution,

we have to use

```
<div id="apptivols" > </div>
<script>
$('#apptivols').fadeIn().delay(5000).queue(function() {

$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "https://d3u46tuvnoj4ah.cloudfront.net/app/v1.1/war/js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js",
success: function(){},
dataType: "script",
cache: true
});

$('#apptivols').show();
  });
</script>
```

instead of `$.getScript('https://d3u46tuvnoj4ah.cloudfront.net/app/v1.1/war/js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js');` this.

Because $.getScript does not have cache property.

Answer (score 1):

It shows like that because thats an easy way to ensure the script will not be cached by your browser. If you reload the page, you will most likely not see the same number again.

According to [this bugrequest](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7578), it a fixed issue. You should update your jQuery to a more recent version.

Comment: Also, the querystring is unlikely to cause any side effects, as the number is randomly generated or base on a timestamp.

Comment: @Jan Dragsbaek but i need to cached that js in my browser. How can i do that?.